# Finding nans in an array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I find `nan`s inside an array?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([3,4,np.nan,1,2])
```

`np.isnan(np.sum())` is useless as it returns only if it has `nan` or not?

Comment: If you're using the newest version of numpy (1.8), there is a new function `np.nansum` to get the sum of all non-nan values: `np.nansum(a)` --> `10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.asarray([3,4,np.nan,1,2])
>>> np.isnan(a)
array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[np.isnan(a)]
array([ nan])

>>> np.where(np.isnan(a))
(array([2], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: And how should I get the indices. Should I use where?